# Razor Page view Error Using VB.net ASP.net Core

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-core

I am converting a C# ASP.net core app to VB.net ASP.net Core and have run into an issue with one of the views that I am trying to get a partial view included into the Razor page.

The error I am getting is:

> Error BC37058
> 'Await' can only be used within an Async method. Consider marking this method with the 'Async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

I have tried several options and it does not seem to help.

The code that is causing the error is

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_topbar.vbhtml")
```

The full Code of the view is as follows:

'''

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_title_meta.vbhtml")
@RenderSection("styles", False)
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_head_css.vbhtml")
```

```
<!-- Begin page -->
<div id="layout-wrapper">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_topbar.vbhtml")
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_sidebar.vbhtml")

    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Start right Content here -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->

    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                
                @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/_Shared/_page_title.vbhtml")

                @RenderBody()
            </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Page-content -->

        @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/_Shared/_footer.vbhtml")
    </div>
    <!-- end main content-->

</div>

@RenderSection("externalhtml", False)

<!-- END layout-wrapper -->
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/_Shared/_right_sidebar.vbhtml")

@RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

Comment: Compare the controllers between the C# and VB project. My guess is the GET method is defined as `async`.

Comment: This error is actually just in the layout view

Comment: I am really stuck still, as soon as I add remove the reference to this view on the pages then there is no error